# Custom Post Type fields not showing in dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type for 'Teams' set up using the code below. However, the fields for 'Latest Discussion' and 'Next Fixture' isn't showing up in the dashboard. I went over the code numerous times and can't find anything wrong with it. I was hoping someone here could help me figure it out.

```
// Register Teams
add_action('init', 'register_teams');

function register_teams() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Teams', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Team', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'team item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Team'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Team'),
        'new_item' => __('New Team'),
        'view_item' => __('View Team'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Teams'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/menu-teams.png',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'has_archive' => true
      );

    register_post_type( 'teams' , $args );
}

// Add Fields
add_action("admin_init", "add_teams_fields");

function add_teams_fields(){
    add_meta_box("latest_discussion", "Latest Discussion", "latest_discussion", "latest discussions", "side", "low");
    add_meta_box("next_fixture", "Next Fixture", "next_fixture", "next fixture", "side", "low");
}

function latest_discussion(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $latest_discussion = $custom["latest_discussion"][0];
    ?>
    <label>Latest Discussion URL:</label><br /><br />
    <input size="40" name="latest_discussion" value="<?php echo $latest_discussion; ?>" />
    <?php
}

function next_fixture(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $next_fixture = $custom["next_fixture"][0];
    ?>
    <label>Next Fixture:</label><br /><br />
    <input size="40" name="next_fixture" value="<?php echo $next_fixture; ?>" />
    <?php
}

// Save Fields
add_action('save_post', 'save_teams_details');

function save_teams_details(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "latest_discussion", $_POST["latest_discussion"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "next_fixture", $_POST["next_fixture"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth argument for `add_meta_box()` is the context, which in this case would be `teams`, not `latest discussion` or `next fixture` as you have here. Also, since you want these metaboxes to show on the new and edit screens for your CPT only, it's easiest to register a metabox callback for your specific CPT and get rid of the action on `admin_init`. Add it to your $args array, e.g. `'register_meta_box_cb' => 'prefix_teams_cpt_add_metaboxes'`. So, a modified version of your code:

```
// Register Teams
add_action('init', 'register_teams');

function register_teams() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Teams', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Team', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'team item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Team'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Team'),
        'new_item' => __('New Team'),
        'view_item' => __('View Team'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Teams'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/menu-teams.png',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'prefix_teams_cpt_add_metaboxes'
      );

    register_post_type( 'teams' , $args );
}

// Add Metaboxes
function prefix_teams_cpt_add_metaboxes(){
    add_meta_box("latest_discussion", "Latest Discussion", "prefix_latest_discussion_metabox", "teams", "side", "low");
    add_meta_box("next_fixture", "Next Fixture", "prefix_next_fixture_metabox", "teams", "side", "low");
}

function prefix_latest_discussion_metabox(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $latest_discussion = $custom["latest_discussion"][0];
    ?>
    <label>Latest Discussion URL:</label><br /><br />
    <input size="40" name="latest_discussion" value="<?php echo $latest_discussion; ?>" />
    <?php
}

function prefix_next_fixture_metabox(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $next_fixture = $custom["next_fixture"][0];
    ?>
    <label>Next Fixture:</label><br /><br />
    <input size="40" name="next_fixture" value="<?php echo $next_fixture; ?>" />
    <?php
}

// Save Fields
add_action('save_post', 'prefix_save_teams_details');

function prefix_save_teams_details(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "latest_discussion", $_POST["latest_discussion"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "next_fixture", $_POST["next_fixture"]);
}
```

Note that I've changed some function names - be sure that you always prefix your functions, and it's way easier to keep track of things like a metabox creating function if the name really describes what it does.

Comment: Thank you very much, Helen. And also, thanks for the prefix tip. I'll keep that in mind for best practices from now on. :)